# Better quality - Printing directly from Word or from PDF?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printer

I have images that are screenshots of some graphs and I want to maintain the best quality. Which option is the best?  Send to printer directly from Word, or converting file into PDF and then to printer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PDF is better as it gives you an exact preview of what you will get. In my experience, Word sometimes messes up formatting and doesn't always provide an accurate preview (learned this the hard way). For more info, check out [this](https://www.soliddocuments.com/pdf/_word_format/170/1?id=170&tag=1)